# How to create a splash screen on Qt?

Tags: qt, splash-screen

I want to create a simple splash screen for my Qt application. I'm learning how to create Qt application and have little knowledge. Any help would be gladly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently created this splash screen, I think you can use it. Make sure to add this in main.cpp

```
QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen;
splash->setPixmap(QPixmap("/PATH/splash.jpg")); // splash picture
splash->show();

MainWindow w;

 QTimer::singleShot(2500, splash,SLOT(close())); // Timer
 QTimer::singleShot(2500,&w,SLOT(show()));
```

Comment: @user7062312 Could you please accept the answer if it works for you?

Comment: Is it possible to make this work with a gif or an animated image?